# Quickblox iOS SDK Signing In using a Facebook access token not working

Tags: ios, quickblox

I'm using the latest Quickblox 2.3.0.4

I cant sign in with Facebook access token.

```
[QBRequest logInWithSocialProvider:@"facebook" accessToken:[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString accessTokenSecret:nil successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user) {
    NSLog(@"qb login succeed");
} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
    NSLog(@"qb login failed"); //it hits this
}];
```

Response header:

```
Response headers: {
   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
   "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
   "Content-Length" = 32;
   "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Wed, 12 Aug 2015 16:54:47 GMT";
   "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
   Server = "nginx/1.0.15";
   Status = "401 Unauthorized";
   "X-Rack-Cache" = "invalidate, pass";
   "X-Request-Id" = 607e9709265a701be551a3eea7d4610a;
   "X-Runtime" = "0.003635";
   "X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
}
```

I tested the access token with graph API: https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token= and it showed valid information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Quickblox docs](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-ios):

> In order to use QuickBlox Users APIs (any QuickBlox API) you must create session.

Try this:

```
// Create session request
[QBRequest createSessionWithSuccessBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBASession *session) {
    //Your Quickblox session was created successfully
    [QBRequest logInWithSocialProvider:@"facebook" accessToken:[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString accessTokenSecret:nil successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user) {
        NSLog(@"qb login succeed");
    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
        NSLog(@"qb login failed");
    }];
} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
    //Handle error here
}];
```